# How do Kik users get their timezone assigned?

Tags: timezone, chatbot, user-data, kik

I am developing a chatbot for Kik messenger, and want to use the current time in the user's timezone to personalize the conversation. According to the [Kik API reference](https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging#user-profiles), users do have a time zone attribute, and I can indeed get the timezone information from a user profile.

However, so far the only timezone value I have encountered is 'None'. So I wonder if this is common... In the Kik messenger app (e.g. the user profile), I have not seen any option to enter a timezone. Does Kik automatically assign a user timezone only in some countries / areas?

The actual question is: How does the Kik messenger assign a timezone to their users, and is to common for a Kik user to have a timezone asigned?

Comment: It would seem very relevant for you to know the end user's time zone info. Can you post and example of a datetime value that you are currently getting, does it have a Z for zulu time?

Comment: @RossBush: [This](http://imgur.com/a/eYubH) is all the time-related info I get: An epoch timestamp and a 'None' timezone.

Comment: The docs you pointed at and the screenshot do not match with regard to the field names.  Are you showing us your data after interpreting it through your code?  If so, you should show us your code.  Preferably just show us the actual raw API response.  It appears from the docs that the `timezone` field should be `null` or an [IANA time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  "None" isn't either of those.

Comment: FWIW, I walked through creating a user account and a bot account and called the user API on myself.  The `timezone` field was indeed `null`.  I would suggest contacting `support@kik.com` to ask why.

Comment: @MattJohnson: I was just printing the raw "user.timezone" value, converted into a string. I am using a Python interface, so "null" translates to a NoneType object. Excellent point about contacting Kik suppor! I will post their answer here, if I get something helpful.